# How do I retrieve the unevaluated value of an attribute from a directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which is using $observe to watch when the value of one of the attributes changes. When this fires, I need to be able to retrieve the *unevaluated* value of the attribute not the evaluated value.

So my HTML would look like this:

```
<div my-attrib="{{scopeVar}}"></div>
```

Then the link function in my directive:

```
attrib.$observe('myAttrib', function(val) {
    // Both val and attrib.myAttrib contain "ABC"
    // I would like the uncompiled value instead
    var evaluatedValue = attrib.myAttrib;
});
```

If the controller had done this:

$scope.myAttrib = "ABC";

When $observe first, evalutedValue returns "ABC". I actually need it to return "{{scopeVar}}".

EDIT: Per the comment below from François Wahl I ended up moving this into a ng-repeat element which is bound to an array of one item. Then I just remove/add the new item in the controller which updates $scope. This eliminates the need to retrieve the uncompiled attribute value and actually cleans things up quite a bit. It's definitely odd when looking at the view since it's not immediately clear as to why it's in a repeater, but it's worth it since it cleans up the code quite a bit.

Comment: `attrib.$observe('myAttrib', function(val) {
    var evaluatedValue = val;
});`

Comment: That also returns "ABC" which was why I was attempting to use attrib.myAttrib directly.

Comment: Whatever you write in {{}} that is uncompiled data for angular and angular will compile it while rendering DOM..

Comment: So there isn't any way to get the uncompiled value?

Comment: `I need to add a new copy of this same element to the page dynamically`: The element represents part of the model. When using AngularJs you make changes to the model and let AngularJs propagate them to the view. You would not directly manipulate the view yourself as that breaks separations of concern AngularJs is trying to adhere to.  -- You could try and use `ng-repeat` and have an array in your model containing the item(s) you wish to make elements for. Then all you would do is add a copy of the item to the list and AngularJs will update the view with a new element for that item.

Comment: This sounded a bit weird but actually works really nicely. It didn't work perfectly for the third party control I'm using but solved (and allowed me to remove) other bits of code. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: <div my-attrib="'{{scopeVar}}'"></div>
above code will keep uncompiled, because i passed it as string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to grab it in the `compile:` function of the directive link this:

```
.directive('myAttrib', function() {
  return {
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var unevaluatedValue = tAttrs.myAttrib;

      return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        attrs.$observe('myAttrib', function(val) {
          // Both val and attrib.myAttrib contain "ABC"
          // I would like the uncompiled value instead
          var evaluatedValue = attrs.myAttrib;

          console.log(unevaluatedValue);
          console.log(evaluatedValue);
        });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/bHDmxJvnENqz8Mpg1qpd?p=preview

Hope this helps.